# How can I convert my date object to use it in Symfony formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, object, formbuilder

I want to use a date in my formbuilder.

When I dump the variable `$date` I get the output:

```
DateTime @1536139353 {#2479 ▼
  date: 2018-09-05 11:22:33.0 Europe/Paris (+02:00)
}
```

When I try to use it now in my formbuilder like this:

```
$options['format'] = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
$options['data'] = new \DateTime($date);
```

Then I get an error message:

```
DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$date` is already a datetime:

```
DateTime @1536139353 {#2479 ▼
  date: 2018-09-05 11:22:33.0 Europe/Paris (+02:00)
}
```

So there is no need to convert it like this `new \DateTime($date);`

The solution is:

```
$options['format'] = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
$options['data'] = $date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just strtotime

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($your_date_string));

or you can  use the DateTime::createFromFormat() static method.

i hope that help you

Comment: I tried `$options['data'] = new \DateTime::createFromFormat($content) ;` but I get the error `syntax error, unexpected 'createFromFormat' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'`

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

The `DateTime` is an object, you will need to get the formatted string from the object here.
Fortunately the `DateTime` object provides the method `format()` which is used to return the date/time as a string in the desired format.
In this example `d.m.Y`, which would output `16.04.2020`.

```
(new \DateTime($date))->format('d.m.Y');
```

## Your use case

It seems you are using `$date` which is already a `DateTime` object to create a new `DateTime` object. This won't work and is not necessary.

Since $date is already an instance of \DateTime, you can directly use

```
$options['format'] = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
$options['data'] = $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

## Sources

### Format

To choose the desired format, look into the documentation here
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

### DateTime Object

You must pass an interpretable string of a date while constructing.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php

Comment: One question, why do you use `'d.m.Y'` for my case when the input is `2018-09-05` ?

Comment: I tried and still get the same error `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Please check my answer now, I have added further information to what your problem is. :)